# Issue with toggling between 3 different height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div with a button "Show more". When clicking on the Show more button height of the div will change in 3 different states.

```
 <div class="segment-suggetion-content height-small">


    <div class="segment-suggetion-show-more">
       <button type="button" class="btn">Show More</button>
     </div>
</div>
```

Initially I have class .height-small with height:200px; When I will click on the button "show more" .height-small will removed and .height-mid will add which have height:400px; 
Again 
If I click on the 'show-more' .height-mid will remove and .height-full will added. And Again clicking on 'show more", the .height-full will change to .height-small.

I am not good at jQuery yet but I tried with this which is not working. I am not sure what is going wrong here.

```
   $('.segment-suggetion-show-more .btn').click(function(){

    if($(".segment-suggetion-content").hasClass('height-small'))
{
    $(".segment-suggetion-content").removeClass('height-small');
    $(".segment-suggetion-content").addClass('height-md');
}

     if($(".segment-suggetion-content").hasClass('height-md'))
{
$(".segment-suggetion-content").removeClass('height-md');
$(".segment-suggetion-content").addClass('height-full');
}

     if($(".segment-suggetion-content").hasClass('height-full'))
{
$(".segment-suggetion-content").removeClass('height-full');
$(".segment-suggetion-content").addClass('height-small');

}
});
```

Any help will be appreciated.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3w5t2kp5/1/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This updated code works:

```
$('.segment-suggetion-show-more .btn').click(function () {

    if ($(".segment-suggetion-content").hasClass('height-small')) {
        $(".segment-suggetion-content").removeClass('height-small');
        $(".segment-suggetion-content").addClass('height-mid');
    }

    else if ($(".segment-suggetion-content").hasClass('height-mid')) {
        $(".segment-suggetion-content").removeClass('height-mid');
        $(".segment-suggetion-content").addClass('height-full');
    }

    else if ($(".segment-suggetion-content").hasClass('height-full')) {
        $(".segment-suggetion-content").removeClass('height-full');
        $(".segment-suggetion-content").addClass('height-small');

    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3w5t2kp5/4/

The 2 problems were:

- you wrote `height-md` instead of `height-mid` in your script
- height of `.height-full` was auto, which is 0 without any content

Comment: Thanks for the solution with explaining the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

here you go: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3w5t2kp5/3/)**

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    
    if($(".segment-suggetion-content").hasClass('height-small'))
    {
        $(".segment-suggetion-content").removeClass('height-small');
        $(".segment-suggetion-content").addClass('height-mid');
    }
     
    else if($(".segment-suggetion-content").hasClass('height-mid'))
    {
        $(".segment-suggetion-content").removeClass('height-mid');
        $(".segment-suggetion-content").addClass('height-full');
    }
     
    else if($(".segment-suggetion-content").hasClass('height-full'))
    {
        $(".segment-suggetion-content").removeClass('height-full');
        $(".segment-suggetion-content").addClass('height-small');   
    }
});
```

**THE PROBLEM:**

the first problem lied in you CSS, you have defined `.segment-suggetion-content.height-full` which would be fine, except it wouldn't be added correctly. you had to change them to `.height-full` and so on!

the next problem was that in your CSS, you've defined `.mid` but in your jQuery called `.md`